# Can't use localhost with MAMP or AMPPS?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I'm trying to start developing my first wordpress theme from scratch, and have hit a wall.

For some reason, one day last week, MAMP stopped working. I'd used it before to view html files, but a couple of days ago it just wouldn't let me view local files in a browser anymore. The lights are all green and the ports are all set to default, but the browser just returns "server not found." So I reinstalled MAMP, then I installed AMPPS, neither of which solved the problem.

I don't really know enough about this stuff to troubleshoot, and I can't find anything on the web that answers my questions. Anyone have a guess?

Comment: You should not [duplicate your own Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18706336/1287812). If you improve, add more details, it will be prompted to the front-page. Anyway, that one is being close-voted as off-topic. This kind of issue should go to [sf] or *maybe* in [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mamp). You should read what's [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) for each site, research the site before asking, and reading [ask] is a plus. Look at the log files for errors: `/Applications/MAMP/logs/*.log` (people need this to help).

Comment: I think your port 80 is busy. 

run `lsof -i :80` in terminal it should show you which application is using port 80. You can kill then the process by `kill <pid>` or `killall <appname>`
You can ask AMPPS support team for help.

Comment: @Jigar I was doing this and the screen is blank.  When I run that command and apache is not running it does not say a program is listening on port 80 but screen is still blank.

Comment: @camdixon which screen ? browser ? or the terminal ?

Comment: @Jigar It was the browser when I clicked on ampps home button or went to localhost/ampps.  I figured out I had to do the advanced skype option to make sure skype did not listen on port 80.  Then I had to entirely reinstall ampps for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying a first theme from scratch myself.  :) AMPPS worked like a dream.

1. Once AMMPS is installed, Open the Application.
2. In the ControlCenter- click the home icon, it should open ampps in a browser window.
3. On the left side of browser window, there will be a wordpress install link inside the     blog category. Click it.
4. Now there will be a blue install button you need to now click in the nav bar of the body.
5. In this new setup window, I set my in directory field to match the database name field.     You don't need to change anything else.
6. Click install.  It should then remind you how successful you are!
7. Next, right click the 2 links it shows you and and open each in a new tab.  Logins are admin and pass.